# how importance is calculated when pre() is used

Tags: r, ensemble-learning

Does anyone know how baseimps are calculated?

```
library(pre)
tree.pre <- pre(A ~ ., data=data_set, tree.unbiased=FALSE, maxdepth=3, ntrees=100)
imps <- importance(tree.pre)
imps$baseimps[1:3,]
```

[image]

`pre()` with CART algorithm was used and all variables are continuous.
`importance()` provides baseimps of the model but have no idea how it's calcaulated.

Comment: You can see the following comment in the [source code](https://github.com/marjoleinF/pre/blob/c360b30a6e6d42033afda26ee9eb6db38af15c5d/R/pre.R#L3111): "baselearner importance is given by abs(coef*SD) (F&P section 6)". Seems to match with the output you have provided & is equation 29 in [this reference](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-statistics/volume-2/issue-3/Predictive-learning-via-rule-ensembles/10.1214/07-AOAS148.full).